# Continuous maps of topological groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, topological-groups

Suppose $\theta: G\to K$ is a homomorphism of topological groups. 
We know that $G$ and $K$ each have fundamental systems of open neighbourhoods of the identity.

If I want to show that $\theta$ is continuous then is it enough to show that $\theta^{-1}(H)$ is open in $G$ where $H$ is an open, *normal* subgroup of $K$? I am guessing this is true but I can't see how to prove it, using the definition of the fundamental system.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $K$ may be a simple group.

Comment: Additionally, in a connected, locally path connected, topological group, the only open normal subgroup (in fact the only open subgroup) is the group itself. This is because open subgroups are also closed.